# Footstep sounds of player for mobile in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, joystick

So I am creating a first person horror game for mobile in Unity in which I am using fixed joystick from joystick pack for character movement. What I am trying to figure out from the past few days is a proper method on how to apply footstep sounds when we move the character through the fixed joystick.  Kindly help me out on this by giving detailed explanation of the method!!!

I tried searching it out on youtube but there is not a single video to explain this. I tried doing it by myself by putting the audio code on some areas of standaloneinput module where I thought that it could work but had no luck in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution I came across given by unity itself called animation event.

This documentation should be able to help you:
[Unity animation events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html)

Just make animation events in your character's animation cycle, those will call methods in which u can play the footstep sounds or do anything else you would like to do.